# How to reuse MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather in a loop

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to learn how to use `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` multiple times, and print out the result after waiting for these two MPI functions to complete. At process 0, top of the program, I want to use a while loop that call Scatter and Gather. Once they are done with all the calculation, I want to send this array back to these functions to do more calculations. I have explained in the code bellow what I am trying to do. Comments in `/*.....*/` are the tasks I am trying to achieve.
 
Following code is run using 4 processors. 
`:$ mpicc test.c -o test`
`:$ mpirun -np 4 test`

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int globaldata[8];
    int localdata[2];
    int counter, i;
    if (rank == 0) 
    {
        for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)//initializing array to all zeros, one time
            globaldata[i] = 0;

        /*counter=0;
        do
        {
            counter++;  */
            printf("Sending at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
            for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
                printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
            printf("\n");

            /*After MPI_Gather is done, I want to get the newly assined array here.
            Now the globaldata array should hold values: 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3
            Therefore, in the next iteration of this while loop, these array values need 
            to be send for a new calculation with Scatter & Gather
        }while(counter<2);*/

        //Following need to be executed after all the scatter and gather has completed
        printf("Finally at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
        for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)//Here the result should be: 0 0 2 2 3 3 4 4
            printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    MPI_Scatter(globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, &localdata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

    localdata[0]= localdata[0]+rank;
    localdata[1]= localdata[1]+rank;

    MPI_Gather(&localdata, 2, MPI_INT, globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {//Currently I can only see the newly assinged array values if I print out the result at the bottom
        printf("At the bottom, Processor %d has data: ", rank);
        for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
            printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**More explanation on what I am trying to do above:**
I am wanting to send my `globaldata` array to all processors. Then get an updated `globaldata` array. once I get the updated array, I want to resend this array back to all other process again to do more calculations. I have written the following code that does a similar job using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. Here I am using MPI_Send to send my array to all processors. Then this array will change it and send back to the root/process 0. Once I get the modified array, `do while` loop will run again and perform more calculation. What I am trying to do is: use MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather in a similar way. Where I get a updated `globaldata` array and send it back to MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather to change that array again

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int globaldata[8];
    int counter, i;
    if (rank == 0) 
    {
        for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
            globaldata[i] = 0;

        counter=0;
        do
        {   /*becase of this do while loop "globaldata" array will always be updated and resend for more caculations*/
            counter++;  
            printf("Sending at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
            for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
                printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
            printf("\n");

            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                MPI_Send(&globaldata, 8, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            for(i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {         
                MPI_Recv(&globaldata, 8, MPI_INT, i, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            }

        }while(counter<2);

        /*Following executes after all the above calculations has completed*/
        printf("Finally at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
        for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
            printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    counter=0;
    do
    {
        counter++; 
        MPI_Recv(&globaldata, 8, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE); 
        globaldata[rank]=globaldata[rank]+rank;
        globaldata[rank+1]=globaldata[rank+1]+rank;
        MPI_Send(&globaldata, 8, MPI_INT, 0, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }while(counter<2);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question either. Do you have something more specific that you don't understand? Do you have some specific problem? Did you try something that didn't work? You should better edit your question to make it clearer. :-)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I have tried explaining what I am trying to achieve here. Hope this will at least help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the scatter and the gather together with the local processing inside the loop:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
   for (i = 0; i < size*2; i++)
      globaldata[i] = 0;
}

for (counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
{
   // if (rank == 0)
   // {
   //    pre-process globaldata
   // }

   MPI_Scatter(globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   localdata[0] += rank;
   localdata[1] += rank;

   MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

   // if (rank == 0)
   // {
   //    post-process globaldata
   // }
}

if (rank == 0)
{
   printf("Finally at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
      for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
         printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Or, if you prefer to keep the logic for the "master" process separate:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
   for (i = 0; i < size*2; i++)
      globaldata[i] = 0;

   for (counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
   {
      // pre-process globaldata

      MPI_Scatter(globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      // Not really useful as rank == 0 and it changes nothing
      localdata[0] += rank;
      localdata[1] += rank;

      MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, globaldata, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      // post-process globaldata
   }

   printf("Finally at Processor %d has data: ", rank);
      for (i=0; i<size*2; i++)
         printf("%d ", globaldata[i]);
   printf("\n");
}
else
{
   for (counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
   {
      MPI_Scatter(globaldata /* or NULL */, 2, MPI_INT, localdata, 2, MPI_INT,
                  0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

      localdata[0] += rank;
      localdata[1] += rank;

      MPI_Gather(localdata, 2, MPI_INT, globaldata /* or NULL */, 2, MPI_INT,
                 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
}
```

Make sure that the loops in both sections of the code have the same number of iterations. Also note that `MPI_Scatter` sends a chunk of `globaldata` to the root rank too and `MPI_Gather` collects a chunk of data from the root, therefore the master process is also expected to perform some data processing.

Comment: @Hristolliev Thank you for showing me with an example and explaining the details. It was very helpful. I guess there is no other way to do this unless I use `if (rank == 0){...}else{...}` ?

Comment: You can write one source file for the master rank and one source file for the workers and either do `if (rank == 0) { master(); } else { worker(); }` somewhere in the main function or utilise the ability of most MPI implementations to have different executables for each rank, e.g., `mpiexec -n 1 ./master : -n 15 ./worker`